# Why am I getting NaN from Mathf.Acos?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im coding physics in C# and unity game engine. I occasionally get a NaN value from this Acos function and I am completely stumped. As you can see in the debug screenshot, I tested the values and they work fine but when using the variable it returns NaN. Please help!

```
float a = Vector3.Dot(waterlineVec.normalized, transform.InverseTransformDirection(velocityVector.normalized));
a = Mathf.Clamp(-1, a, 1);
alpha = Mathf.Acos(a); //alpha in radians
```

[image]

Comment: Does `alpha = Mathf.Acos(1f);` return `NaN`?

Comment: Nope it returns 0 the same as Mathf.Acos(1)

Comment: Can you reproduce if you add `System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();` after `.Clamp()` but before `.Acos()`?  And what about if you change the second line to `var b = Mathf.Clamp(-1, a, 1);` and then `alpha = Mathf.Acos(b);`?

Comment: Note sure about current problem, but note that `Clamp` first argument is value, second is min and third is max. You pass `a` there as min, so if a is greater than 1 - Clamp will return `a`, and `Acos` then will return `NaN`. I suppose your intention was `Mathf.Clamp(a, -1, 1)`

Comment: EvK cheers for that note! Fixing my clamp to your suggestion fixes the problem. However, I added the clamp to try and test the whole NaN error in the first place, strictly speaking it isn't neccessary. I suspect something is happening with my Dot calculation which is returning a value only slightly above 1 like 1.00000001 or something like that which is out of bounds but isn't displaying on my debugger. Thanks for your help. Still not sure about the original problem though.

Comment: It made sense for `Mathf.Acos(a)` to be `NaN` given the code, but it didn't make sense for `Mathf.Acos(a)` to be `NaN` _when_ `a==1f`.  That felt like it may've been a consequence of the evaluations getting misordered, which a `System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier()` (or, if necessary, a `Thread.Sleep(1000)`) might help test.

Comment: Weird, the dot product of two normalized vectors should always be between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too, with almost identical code. In my case, I was using `Mathf.Clamp01(a)`, which is equivalent to `Mathf.Clamp(a, 0, 1)`. I really can't explain why, but it seems that this could be resolved by replacing this function call with:

```
if(a > 1.0f)
    a = 1.0f;
if(a < 0.0f)
    a = 0.0f;
```

I had thought that this might be because `Mathf.Clamp01` casts the floats to doubles before doing a comparison (as seen by decompiling the UnityEngine library), but even when I do this myself in the code this doesn't reproduce this issue - so I'm at a bit of a loss as to the cause - but this does fix it.